# How to call a js method with parameters inside of json?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to call `AddHour (first, second).` I achieved the call `Now()` method without parameters. Though AddHour has 2 parameters, I can not access AddHour method. The try gives me  following error back:" **Additional information: first is not defined**"
How can I call `Addhour()` inside my json object?

```
var f = {
    Now: Now(),
    Today: Today(),
    Yesterday: Yesterday(),
    Tomorrow: Tomorrow(),
    ThisMonth: ThisMonth(),
    ThisYear: ThisYear(),
    AddHour : AddHour(first,second),
    DateDiff: function (first, second) {
        return first+second;
    }
}
function AddHour (first, second) {
    return first+second;
}
function Now() {
    var date = new XDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var second = date.getSeconds();
    return ConvertToLONG(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

}
```

Comment: There's no JSON there, that's just JavaScript.

Comment: The fact that you have a JavaScript object literal is irrelevant. `first` is not defined because you don't define it, I can't see any sign of you even trying to define it anywhere. What value do you expect it to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify arguments when using AddHour in object. You could declare it like this:

```
ThisYear: ThisYear(),
AddHour : AddHour,
DateDiff: function (first, second) {
    return first+second;
}
```

You passed arguments to method in your code and Javascript tried to find these arguments, hence the error (you were trying not to assign function to property, but to CALL function with two arguments - `(first, second)` and assign its result to property, which - in your case - is incorrect).

Additional notes - there is no JSON here, as mentioned in comments by others. You are creating Javascript object - your `f` is this object.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues there:

First of all, you are confused about JSON: a Javascript object is not JSON, JSON is a way to store information in a JS-like format. So what you have there is just a JS object.

Second issue: If you want to assign a function as an attribute, the correct way is the following:

```
function myFn(first,second) {
  return first+second;
}

var objecWithFunction= {
  myAttr: myFn
}
```

Because if you put parameters, you are obtaining the result of executing that function:

```
var objectWithResult = {
  myAttr: myFn(1,2); //myAttr will store the number 3, not the function
}
console.log(objecWithFunction.myAttr(1,2)); //it will print 3
console.log(objectWithResult.myAttr ); //it will print 3
```

Your code is failing because the interpreter cannot find the variables `first` and `second` in order to execute the function, but I think that is not what you meant.